# How to download a file from a website via terminal?

Tags: command-line, url

Suppose that we have a full URL of desired file e.g.

> http://domain.com/directory/4?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=file.tgz

I would like to go without installing a new software. Is it possible?

Command

```
 cp  'http://example.com/directory/4?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=file.tgz' hooray
```

doesn't work ;)

Comment: `wget` is your friend here :)

Comment: `wget` is perhaps the simplest way but you can also use `curl`. [Read this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/wget-curl/)

Comment: Use `wget -O hooray "http://domain.com/directory/4?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=file.tgz"`. You can add `-c` option to resume download if connection was lost while downloading file.

Comment: "hooray" cracked me up LOL

Answer (score 510, accepted):

Open terminal and type

```
wget "http://domain.com/directory/4?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=file.tgz"
```

to download the file to the current directory.

```
wget  -P /home/omio/Desktop/ "http://thecanadiantestbox.x10.mx/CC.zip"
```

will download the file to `/home/omio/Desktop`

```
wget  -O /home/omio/Desktop/NewFileName "http://thecanadiantestbox.x10.mx/CC.zip"
```

will download the file to `/home/omio/Desktop` and give it your `NewFileName` name.

Comment: Beat me to the punch. Dang.

But yeah, it's `wget [whatever web address]`. If you want to choose the location, type `cd [local location on your computer.]` **EXAMPLE:** `cd /home/omio/Desktop/` | `wget http://thecanadiantestbox.x10.mx/CC.zip`

Comment: @Omio There is no need to run `cd`. You can just specify output file via `-O` option. For example: `wget -O /home/omio/Desktop/file.tgz "http://domain.com/directory/4?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=file.tgz"`

Comment: Your examples will not work. You MUST use quotes when URL contains ampersands.

Comment: @Sergey Thanks for the clarification. I haven't had to use wget yet, but I would have to, in the future.

Comment: ? and & are interpreted by your shell. You need to quote or escape it. Generally, you have a shortcut to paste a quoted or escaped version of the string in the clipboard in your terminal. Be very careful when pasting stuffs inside a terminal.

Comment: That's a simple answer. :)

Comment: wget -P /home/omio/Desktop/ "http://thecanadiantestbox.x10.mx/CC.zip" because /home/omio/Desktop/ is a folder

Answer (score 49):

you can do it by using curl .

```
curl -O http://domain.com/directory/4?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=file.tgz
```

The -O saves the file with the same name as in the url rather than dumping the output to stdout

For more [information](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: I can never remember if it's a zero or O

Comment: -O is the alphabetical letter and must be capital, else a log will be generated

Answer (score 22):

I use `axel` and `wget` for downloading from terminal, axel is download accelerator

**syntax**

axel

[image: Install via the software center]

```
axel www.example.com/example.zip
```

wget

```
wget -c www.example.com/example.zip
```

for more details type `man axel`, `man wget` in terminal

Comment: how is `axel` different from `wget`?

Comment: @heinrich5991 wget is more advanced than axel!

Answer (score 9):

Just to add more flavor to this question, I'd also recommend that you take a look at this:

`history -d $((HISTCMD-1)) && echo '[PASSWORD]' | sudo -S shutdown now`

You could use this to shutdown your computer after your `wget` command with a `;` perhaps or in a `bash` script file.

This would mean you don't have to stay awake at night and monitor until your download as (un)successfully run.

[Read this answer as well](https://askubuntu.com/a/136664/41821)

Answer (score 7):

the lack of Aria2 mention is just a disservice so with that said, check out Aria2. https://aria2.github.io/

Install it by simply typing in terminal:

```
sudo apt install aria2
```

Then simply type this to download the file:

```
aria2c http://example.com/directory/4?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=file.tgz
```

You can find more help with `aria2` by its `man` page.

Comment: What is the benefit to Aria2? Your answer could be improved by briefly explaining why it is worth installing another tool instead of just using `curl` or `wget`.

Answer (score 3):

I did these steps
From Oh-my-zsh,

```
brew install wget
wget https://github.com/sencha-extjs-examples/QuickStart/archive/master.zip
```