# How can i display php/html code output into terminal not browser?

Tags: 14.04, php

I am new in ubuntu. So i am facing some problem with terminal command.So please help me.
can i execute my php code in my terminal not my browser as like using localhost?

Comment: no i think this is not like that answer.  we r using localhost to view php output in browser but i want to see my output in terminal.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/207265/158442 then, since you just want to open a URL

Comment: its not downloading from a website. please try to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to understand the question because the final output of PHP web sites is HTML code, which can be interpreted from the web browser but can't be interpreted from the terminal itself. [This article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKkJ8.png) sheds more light on this subject.

Let's assume we have pretty simple PHP program, called `test.php`, which looks like that:

```
$ cat /var/www/html/test.php

<?php
        print "\n";      
        echo "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";

        print "\n";
        $a = '5';
        $b = '10';
        echo "<code>The result is: " . $c = $b / $a . "</code>";

        print "\n";
        print "\n";    # we need these lines to align the output into the terminal
?>
```

We can display the output of this code in several ways:

- When we open this program in the web browser - as a web page - the result will looks like:

  [image]
- The actual result of our PHP program - page's source code is:

  [image]
- If *test.php* is executed as PHP program into the terminal, then we will get identical result - `php test.php`:

  [image]
- If we want to execute the same program into the terminal through the web interface we can use `curl` in this way - `curl http://mysite.dev/test.php`:

  [image]
- Or we can use `wget` in [this way](https://raamdev.com/2007/using-wget-to-run-a-php-script/) - `wget -O - -q  http://mysite.dev/test.php`:

  [image]
- If we want to see the result of the interpretation of the HTML code into the terminal, we must use some text-based web browser like as [Lynx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser)) - `lynx http://mysite.dev/test.php`:

  [image]

Comment: thank you so much. i got it. this is what i actually want to know. @spas Spasov

Comment: yes grant it. thanks a lot.can you please tell me if i do a big project which output will show in terminal like this. is  it better way for me?

Comment: @Arman I think there is no difference between these three approaches (php/curl/wget). But, I'm not sure how much readable will be the output of big project into a terminal. You can make `test.php` which contains `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and "curl" it to see the result.