# "google-chrome <file>" downloads the file instead of opening it

Tags: google-chrome

As the title says: `google-chrome index.php`downloads the file immediately instead of opening it. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The original answer:**

The browser itself cannot run PHP code. You need a web server to interpret a PHP file as web page, that can be displayed through the browser.

If it is a `.html` file, it will be displayed. Try to create simple HTML file as next and call it `index.html`, for example:

```
<html>
    <header><title>This is title</title></header>
    <body>Hello world!</body>
</html>
```

Then run:

```
google-chrome index.html
```

Something more, if you type `google-chrome ind` and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> the rest part of the file name (`ex.html`) will be autocomplete. But if it is `index.php` the autocompletion will not work.

---

**More detailed answer:**

The browsers their-self cannot run [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) code. Mainly they work with [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) and some scripting languages as [JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript). That we see in the browser's window is a result of the interaction between the [web server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server) on the one hand and the client's [web browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser#Function) on the other hand.

The PHP code is executed onto the [server side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side) and there must be installed [interpretation program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language) - so called [`php`](https://secure.php.net/). Within Ubuntu, with installed [`php`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04), if we have a simple PHP scenario, to display it into the browser's window we don't need a web server:

- Let's assume we have this file:

  ```
  $ cat index.php 

  <?php
      echo "<html>\n";
      echo "\t<header><title>This is title</title></header>\n";
      echo "\t<body>Hello world!</body>\n";
      echo "</html>\n";
  ?>
  ```
- The output of its interpretation is:

  ```
  $ php index.php 

  <html>
      <header><title>This is title</title></header>
      <body>Hello world!</body>
  </html>
  ```
- So, we can redirect the output to a new file and then we can run this new file via the browser:

  ```
  php index.php > index.html && chromium-browser index.html &
  ```

  <sup>* *In my case it is `chromium-browser` instead of `google-chrome`.*</sup>
- The result will be:

  [image]

---

Partly related topic: [How can i display php/html code output into terminal not browser?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892891/how-can-i-display-php-html-code-output-into-terminal-not-browser)