# How to shutdown automatically from command line in 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04, 13.10, shutdown

I know there is already [a similar question about this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283984). But that question was only about how to get the shutdown dialog in general. I need to get back the countdown of the old shutdown dialog (Ubuntu <= 12.10) which shutdown the system after 60sec.

geobuntu suggested this dbus call in his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/288452/37580):

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest="org.gnome.Shell" /org/gnome/SessionManager/EndSessionDialog org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog.Open uint32:2 uint32:0 uint32:60 array:objpath:/org/gnome/SessionManager/EndSessionDialog
```

`qdbus` indicate that third argument is `max_wait` which should (in my opinion) set and start the countdown:

```
~$ qdbus org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/SessionManager/EndSessionDialog
[...]
method void org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog.Open(uint type, uint arg_1, uint max_wait, QList<QDBusObjectPath> inhibitors)
```

But it doesn't. I already tried various values for `type` and `arg_1` without luck.

---

EDIT: Actually the countdown is more 'nice to have'. What I really need is that the system WILL shutdown without any extra user action. It should work without `sudo` (including any no-password sudoers).

I would prefer dbus calls cause I already have a nice [list of dbus calls](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~bit-team/backintime/trunk/view/887/common/tools.py#L702) which will shutdown all DE's except Unity >= 13.04

---

EDIT2: I had a look into [Unity source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity/trunk/view/head:/UnityCore/GnomeSessionManager.cpp#L162). I don't know `C++` but for me it looks like `arg1` and `timeout_length` are not handled in source (can someone with `C++` knowledge please confirm this?). Maybe this will be added in later releases.

---

EDIT3: I reported this as [bug #1256703](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1256703) on Launchpad.

Comment: In command line, `sudo shutdown +1` would work, but that will just shutdown in a minute unless cancelled *(Either by Ctrl-C, or `sudo shutdown -c`)*. I know this is not what you asked, but it may be useful anyway.

Comment: That will also need `sudo`. I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: You don't have to include sudo - see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/136660/how-to-shutdown-a-linux-machine-including-the-root-password-in-1-line) and [here](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_allow_non-super_users_to_shutdown_computer_in_Linux). But, one of the problems is, with Linux, with doing things via command line, it often has to be done as root... *(e.g. controlling internet connection)*. As for the opening the old dialog, I ain't got any idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a [great answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/385316/37580) from [Majal Mirasol](https://askubuntu.com/users/101985/majal-mirasol) about this. He suggested to use

```
/usr/bin/dbus-send --system --print-reply \
--dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" \
/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager \
org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

This will work perfectly for me.

If you like this solution please send kudos to Majal's answer and not this one.

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo visudo` in the terminal and add the following line:

```
%user_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/reboot, /sbin/shutdown
```

This allows you to run the above three commands, **using sudo**, however with no password.

So, `sudo poweroff` will now result in a password less shutdown.

then create an alias by putting  the following at the end of `~/.bashrc_aliases` by opening it as -

```
gedit ~/.bash_aliases
```

and add the following in the last -

```
alias shutdown='sudo shutdown -h now'
```

Now lets load the changes to the .bash_aliases file.

```
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Try `shutdown` . hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks @Sushantp606. Sure this will work on my own system. But I need this for OSS project BackInTime (https://launchpad.net/backintime) and I don't want to mess around in users sudoers file for this.

Comment: While this question is specific to 13.04, it should be noted that by default `poweroff` is now non-root accessible in more recent versions of Ubuntu starting with 15.04 due to switch to `systemd`